# How can i validate existing username in database using mysql in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I'm doing a registration form in c# 
the code is working really well, but the the problem is even if the username 
is already exist in the database it's still able to duplicate username. 
How can i add a restriction for having a duplicate value for username?
So here is my code  ps. i didn't add the exception because it's too long.

```
 string condense = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=''";
        string milk = "insert into empaccount.empinfo(IDNUMBER,email,username,password,firstname,lastname,cnumber) values ('" + this.idnumber.Text + "','" + email.Text + "','" + username.Text + "','" + password.Text + "','" + firstname.Text + "','" + this.lastname.Text + "','" + contactno.Text + "');";
        MySqlConnection conDatabase = new MySqlConnection(condense);
        MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(milk, conDatabase);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(idnumber.Text))
        {
            idnumber.Text = " Please generate an id number";
        }
          else
         {
             conDatabase.Open();
             myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();
             MessageBox.Show("You're Registered!", "Successful!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

             while (myReader.Read())
             {

             }
         }
```

Comment: Can you add a unique constraint on the empinfo table?

Comment: i edited my post.. Where can i find it?

Comment: In the database schema where the table is created.

Comment: but i want to make an exception inside the form to show that the MessageBox.Show("username is already exist"); something like that.

Comment: If you use a unique index and try to insert a duplicate key it will throw an exception, you can trap it, examine and determine if it was caused by a duplicate.

Comment: Also, for an insert don't use ExecuteReader, use just Execute, a reader is used when you need to read data from the result of a query (and finally, if you use a reader destroy it after using).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a unique limitation (constraint) to your table, using whatever database editor you used to create it. Then, catch an exception thrown by your application if the username is taken.

Basically, if there is some username already there, and you have a unique constraint on the username field in the table, your program will throw an exception when you try to add to it. Here is an example:

Also, if you are doing an insert query, you don't need to ExecuteRead(). Just do ExecuteNonQuery() and it will run the query without needing to return anything.

```
    string condense = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=''";
    string milk = "insert into empaccount.empinfo(IDNUMBER,email,username,password,firstname,lastname,cnumber) values ('" + this.idnumber.Text + "','" + email.Text + "','" + username.Text + "','" + password.Text + "','" + firstname.Text + "','" + this.lastname.Text + "','" + contactno.Text + "');";
    MySqlConnection conDatabase = new MySqlConnection(condense);
    MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(milk, conDatabase);
    MySqlDataReader myReader;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(idnumber.Text))
    {
        idnumber.Text = " Please generate an id number";
    }
    else
    {
      conDatabase.Open();
      try {
        cmdDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
      catch {
        //Username is taken
      }
      MessageBox.Show("You're Registered!", "Successful!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
     }
```

Comment: after i added an exception
else
            {
                conDatabase.Open();

            }
            try
            {
                cmdDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username is already taken");
            }
            MessageBox.Show("You're Registered!", "Successful!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        }
the second messagebox is showing how to stop it? although it doesn't saving but it shouldn't be showing after the first messagebox

Comment: The "You are registered" box is showing even if the "Username is taken" shows? If that's the case, add 'return;' right after the "username is taken" in the catch.